# Is it possible to edit a SwiftUI list element in the detail view?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to edit the properties of a list element in the detail view of the NavigationView in SwiftUI. If I edit a property of the element in the same view, the list is updated automatically.
If I open the detail-view of the list element and edit the property, it is stored in the element correctly and is also accessible in the main view, but the list is not updated.
Here is the section of the code:

```
@ObservedObject var actions: ActionsList =  ActionsList(l:[Action(dur: 1),Action(dur: 5), Action(dur: 10) ])

NavigationView{
                List(actions.list, id: \.id ){ action in
                NavigationLink(destination: ActionDetail(action:action)){
                    Timer_cell( action: action)
                }
} 
            }
```

ActionDetail:

```
struct ActionDetail: View {
    @State var action: Action

    var body: some View {
        Form {

            HStack {
                Text("Dauer")
                Spacer()
                TextField("Dauer", value: $action.duration, formatter: self.numberFormatter)
            }
        }

    }


    var numberFormatter : Formatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

ActionList:

```
import Foundation

class ActionsList: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list :Array<Action> = [];
    init(l : Array<Action>) {
        list = l;
    }
    init(){
        list = []
    }
}
```

Action:

```
struct Action : Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable{
    static func == (lhs: Action, rhs: Action) -> Bool {
        lhs.duration == rhs.duration && lhs.type == rhs.type && lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    var active: Bool
    var duration: Int       //in seconds
    var type: ActionType
    var id: UUID
    init() {
        active = true
        duration = 10
        type = ActionType.active
        id = UUID()
    }
    init(dur: Int){
        active = true
        duration = dur
        type = ActionType.active
        id = UUID()
    }
    init(_id: UUID, _type: ActionType, dur: Int, _active: Bool){
        id = _id
        type = _type
        duration = dur
        active = _active
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(duration)
        hasher.combine(type)
        hasher.combine(active)
    }
}
enum ActionType {
    case pause, active, warmup, cooldown
}
```

Comment: can you share details view code where you are updating property ?

Comment: I updated the question and added the code

Comment: can you please add code for the ActionsList model ?

Comment: I have also added the struct of the list element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to change actions list to environment variable like below

```
@EnvironmentObject var actions: ActionsList
```

and you can call ListView from below code

```
    let contentView = ActionListView().environmentObject(ActionsList(l:[Action(dur: 1),Action(dur: 5), Action(dur: 10) ]))
```

While navigating to Detail View

```
NavigationView{
            List(actions.list.indices){ index in
                NavigationLink(destination: ActionDetail().environmentObject(self.actions.list[index])){
                    Timer_cell( action: self.$actions.list[index]) // this line does the trick
                        }
              }
 }
```

Change your Action model `struct` to `Class` and conform to `Observable` protocol

```
class Action : Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable, ObservableObject {
    static func == (lhs: Action, rhs: Action) -> Bool {
        lhs.duration == rhs.duration && lhs.type == rhs.type && lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    var active: Bool
    @Published var duration: Int 
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped a lot! But I also had to edit the Timercell